# Import json file to Choregraphe from Flask server

Tags: python, flask-restful, nao-robot, choregraphe

I 'm trying to write a code which will send a json file from a flask server to chregraphe in order to program a NAO robot. I want to parse a random number from 1 to 3 and NAO say the number accordingly. Unfortunately i haven't managed to do it.

The code that i use to send the number from flask server is

```
import http.client
import json
import random
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    IP = "10.0.0.23"  # The IP address of my robot
    PORT = 9559

    
    number = random.randint(1, 3)

    data = json.dumps({"number": number})

    # Connect to Choregraphe
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(IP, PORT)

    # Send the data to Choregraphe
    headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    conn.request("POST", "/module/ALMemory/value/ExampleKey", data, headers)

    return "Data sent to Choregraphe: " + data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm trying to send the number to the "Examplekey"

Also i use a python script box in choregraph with the beneath code

```
def onInput_onStart(self, p):
    # Connect to ALMemory
    memory = ALProxy("ALMemory")

    # Read the value stored under the key "ExampleKey"
    data = memory.getData("ExampleKey")

    # Parse the JSON string into a dictionary
    data = json.loads(data)

    # Get the "number" value from the dictionary
    number = data["number"]

   if number == 1:
     text = "one"
   elif number == 2:
     text = "two"
  else
    text = "three"


  tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "10.0.0.23", 9559)
  tts.say(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Tolis to StackOverflow!

While it might be starting a Flask server, your first snippet of code seems rather focused on sending an HTTP request to http://10.0.0.23:9559, where I suppose NAOqi is listening to - and NAOqi does not "speak" HTTP, it speaks Qi.

If you want to send data via HTTP, you will need to get a Flask server running on the robot, and call the relevant NAOqi APIs in response.

But bringing Flask to the robot (via Choregraphe) is no easy task. Instead I would recommend that your client code directly uses [the Python SDK for NAOqi 2.5](https://www.aldebaran.com/fr/support/pepper-naoqi-2-9/downloads-softwares) (better for Python 2.x) or [libQi Python](https://pypi.org/project/qi/) (better for Python 3.x).

The client code would look like this (not tested):

```py
import qi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qi.Application(sys.argv)
    app.start()
    memory = session.service("ALMemory")
    number = random.randint(1, 3)
    service.setData("ExampleKey", number)
```